# Is there any standard combo box element that I can use in the interface builder of Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any standard combo box element that I can use in the interface builder of Xcode? Or should I use picker view in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A picker view is the iOS equivalent of a combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `picker view` as it is a standard control and do the same functionality of combo box.iPhone users are more user friendly with `PickerView` instead of combo box.You can see in all standard application `picker view` is used instead of combo box.So picker view is more relevant and user friendly to use.